# OpenGL Find GPU limits on device

Tags: android, opengl-es, gpu

I am trying to build an app that use OpenGL.

In short , i’m use onPreviewFrame for capture frame from camera 
and send that frame to the OpenGL.

in most common device i get what i’m want.

till i try it on partnertech EM-100 Tablet And strange thing happened.

the 1st image is ok but after that all go wrong.

same images:

1st input:
[image]

1st grayScaleFilter:
[image]

2nd input:
[image]

2st grayScaleFilter:
[image]

I suspect that the GPU of this Tablet is low in memory or it have some limit on OpenGL tasks.

how can i debug what is going on this device???